# How can i check the exact bug in mail

Tags: php, email

```
<?php

  $email_to = "xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.com";
  $email_subject = 'Testing EXIM4';
  $email_message = 'exim test local';

  // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: qqqqqqqq@qqqqqqqqqqqq.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  $result = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

  if ($result)
  echo 'Mail accepted for delivery ';
  if (!$result)
  echo 'Test unsuccessful... ';
  ?>
```

I am using above code to send the mail (E-mail id changed) 
It prints

'Mail accepted for delivery '

but I am not receiving mail.Please help.

Comment: Have you check spam?

Answer (score 0):

> `mail` Returns `TRUE` if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, `FALSE`
> otherwise.
>
> ***It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.***

The above is from PHP [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-returnvalues) documentation. If you want to be a bit more precise on validating mail delivery you could try [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).